# blank message on password reset with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, passwords, registration

I get blank message without the password reset message and link, when I request to reset my password. I am using `devise`

Here is my passwords controller:

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController  
  def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)  
    respond_with({}, :location => after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
  end
end
```

registrations controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController    
  def create
    if verify_recaptcha
      super
    else
      build_resource
      clean_up_passwords(resource) 
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: { passwords: 'passwords' }  

  devise_for :users, :path_names=> {:sign_in=> "login", :sign_out=> "logout"}, 
  :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' }
```

Comment: what version if devise are you using?

Comment: am using devise-2.1.2